# Limitations of division in Python

Tags: python, division

I wrote a simple Python code that divides 1 by 2. My aim was to see the limits of division. The code runs fine till a little bit over than a thousand cycles. Then it starts to produce 0.0 instead of any representation of a number. Why is that happening? 
I am just learning.

I paste here the last few result lines:

6.3e-322
3.16e-322
1.6e-322
8e-323
4e-323
2e-323
1e-323
5e-324
0.0
0.0
Press any key to continue . .

Comment: It can't represent / store numbers that small.

Comment: If you need better precision, you could use a `Decimal` object from the `decimal` module.

Comment: It can't, I see. But why that limitation exists?

Comment: You are dividing continuously 1 by 2 etc. This is always limited, even if you do it with pen and paper, either you run out of time, or paper, or pen or oxygen to breath. Same with a computer.

Comment: The limitations exist because the computer is using a fixed number of bits to represent a floating point. See here for more information: http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python floats are IEEE double-precision floating point numbers (that is, whatever your platform's C compiler maps to the "double" type -- on most current OSes, that means 64-bit).

You can learn about them here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point_number

If you need arbitrary-precision maths, you can use the `decimal` module. It will, of course, be slower, but you'll be able to keep dividing by 2 until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import sys
print sys.float_info
```

It will give you an idea about the limits of the float numbers on your system. I expect it should be about the same as the numbers you got.